# Sharepoint Workflow: How do I get the "BeforeProperties" in a WorkflowItemChanged event handler

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, workflow

I've got a sharepoint workflow with a state where I'm waiting to see what changes the user makes to the list item the workflow is attached to.

My state has a "OnWorkflowItemChanged" activity.  On that activity I've bound the "AfterProperties" and "BeforeProperties" which created the following members in the code behind:

```
public Hashtable m_listItemBefore = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
public Hashtable m_listItemAfter = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
```

I then added a method for the Invoked event on the activity and thought I'd be fine.  However, when the code reaches my Invoked function, the m_listItemAfter object contains all the new information, but the m_listItemBefore is empty.

Similarly, if I access the list item directly through:

```
this.workflowProperties.Item["field name"]
```

I'm also getting the new values.

The logic of my workflow requires that I see what they changed the data FROM as well as the new values.  Any ideas on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe BeforeProperties are only available in synchronous events (ItemAdding, ItemUpdating) and not asynchronous events (ItemAdded, ItemUpdated).

This is quite a bummer and has bothered me a bit in the past, but I'm pretty sure that's right.  So, if you really have to have the BeforeProperties, you have to resort to a synchronous event.

Comment: Agreed. I think Clyde needs an Event Handler instead of a workflow.